# Handling of images by laptop screen

Tags: display

Suppose, I have a laptop whose monitor holds the following specifications- 19''(diagonal), 16:9 aspect ratio, say 1920x1080 pixel dimensions. Now , let width be 'b' and height be 'a'. Given, b/a is 16:9 and b^2+a^2=(19'')^2(from Pythagoreas theorem). So, b comes out to be 14.43''. Now b contains 1920 pixels. This implies there are 133.3 pixels/inch in my monitor screen. This is how my pixel grid is structured. So here is my question:

How does my monitor that is fixed in above specifications handle images of different dimensions. I want to understand a scenario where I have an image of dimension half that of my monitor(say, 960x540). So, is the image scaled to fill the entire grid in my monitor. If so,

1. Who takes care of the interpolation?
2. How is the interpolation done?

Comment: It's called scaling, either by hardware or software.

Comment: How does hardware do it? And which mechanism does it follow? Can you elaborate on that part?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling